# Make Jasmine wait for Async function to complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write tests for functions that call Async functions from a service and I can not for the life of me figure out how to make Jasmine wait for my Async operations to finish before executing the expect function.

```
  describe('vm.submitLogin', function () {
    var $scope;
    var $q;
    var deferred;
    var $controller;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$q_, LoginService, $httpBackend) {
      $q = _$q_;
      $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      $controller = _$controller_;
      deferred = _$q_.defer();

      spyOn(LoginService, 'login').and.callFake(function () {
        return $.Deferred().resolve({success: true, twoFactorRequired: false});
      });

      $httpBackend.expectGET("/data/I/need/to/mock").respond({"uri": "http://localhost:8081/data/I/need/to/mock.json"});

      var vm = $controller('LoginCtrl', { $scope: $scope});

      vm.submitLogin();

      $scope.$apply();
    }));

    it('should work, please work...', inject (function ($httpBackend, LoginService) {

      expect(something);

    }));
  });
```

I have tried to use Jasmine's "done" function, but I cannot figure out how to go about implementing it.

In this example, as soon as

```
$scope.$apply();
```

is called, It right away jumps to the expect and fails because the async operations has yet to finish.

Comment: The first thing is that `inject` wrapper is synchronous. The second is that you probably have XY problem. What did make you think that the specs should be async? What does `$.Deferred` do in Angular spec in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [$httpBackend.flush()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) before $scope.$apply() as referred in angular documentation:

> The $httpBackend used in production always responds to requests
>   asynchronously. If we preserved this behavior in unit testing, we'd
>   have to create async unit tests, which are hard to write, to follow
>   and to maintain. But neither can the testing mock respond
>   synchronously; that would change the execution of the code under test.
>   For this reason, the mock $httpBackend has a flush() method, which
>   allows the test to explicitly flush pending requests. This preserves
>   the async api of the backend, while allowing the test to execute
>   synchronously.