# Async function didn not complete within 5000ms

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular15

I'm trying to test that the gridApi is initialized properly but I'm getting the error: Async function didn not complete within 5000ms.
*There are times when the code runs fine but there are time when I must run the code 100 times for it to pass*

```
let component: SGridComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SGridComponent>;
let data$: Observable<Criteria[]>=new BehaviorSubject(
[{
id: "some",
lob: "some"
}])

const columnDefs = [
 { field: 'id' },
 { field: 'priorityOrder' }
]

beforeEach(async () => {
 await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 imports: [AgGridModule, matIconModule, ngSelectModule],
 declarations:[SGridComponent]
 }).compileComponents();
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SGridComponent);
 component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
 fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should test if ag-grid exists in HTML', () => {
component.columnDefs = columnDefs;
component.data=data$;
const grid = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('ag-grid-angular');
expec(grid).not.toBeNull();
}
```

This is my ts component:

```
export class UicGridComponent {
 gridApi: any;
 gridColumnApi: any;

 @Input
 columnDefs: any;

 @Input
 data: any;
 
 onGridReady(params: any){
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  this.data.subscribe((data:any) => {
   params.api.setRowData(data);
  };
 };
}
```

Comment: is the data$ completing?

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if the data$ completes

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { matIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { ngSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { SGridComponent } from './s-grid.component';

let component: SGridComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<SGridComponent>;
let data$: Observable<Criteria[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Criteria[]>([
  {
    id: 'some',
    lob: 'some'
  }
]).pipe(
  // Complete the observable after emitting its initial value
  finalize(() => console.log('data$ completed'))
);

const columnDefs = [
  { field: 'id' },
  { field: 'priorityOrder' }
];

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [AgGridModule, matIconModule, ngSelectModule],
    declarations: [SGridComponent]
  }).compileComponents();
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SGridComponent);
  component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should test if ag-grid exists in HTML', () => {
  component.columnDefs = columnDefs;
  component.data = data$;
  const grid = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('ag-grid-angular');
  expect(grid).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Jasmine will timeout after 5sec, perhaps it's to bussy though and you have a race condition

Comment: Hi @Walter Verhoeven, I tried your code and didn't work, still throwing the error.

Comment: @AlexRodriguez, can you share the error and all the code?

Comment: @AlexRodriguez, perhaps you share some more code and errors? Also dis you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044469/make-jasmine-wait-for-async-function-to-complete?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There's a local issue that generates this type of error because sometimes it passes other times it doesn't.